# Can not join to active directory

Tags: windows, dns, active-directory

I installed ws2016 server as a domain controller on virtualbox using internal network .

Everything was successfully installed about active directory and i created domain name as 'stark.local'

Also i created another ws2016 on virtualbox using internal network and I want to join new virtual machine to my domain controller.

Can ping dns server(which is my domain controller) and also Firewall off, no anti-virus installed.

However when i try to join dc it gives below error;

[image]

what i realized that i can not make nslookup to my dns server ip.

Even if on domain controller can not nslookup its self.

ipconfig of Domain Controller

[image]

ipconfig of node1;

[image]

I had no hair now and need your help.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved!

The problem was using internal network. I changed to host-only network and it worked.

Comment: Glad to hear that! So that's a thing of virtual machines, in the "real world" it should work then and my whole answer might be more helpful. Check the end of my answer for a little explanation on that ;)

Answer (score 0):

### AC DC

Using public IP addresses will always get you in trouble, try changing them to something like:
*192.168.1.10* & *192.168.1.20*

(Please read entire answer before modifying)

Also, i would recommend checking this link on the [official microsoft forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2da7e03b-5818-4cec-a504-cc094f4b5d15/active-directory-domain-controller-could-not-be-contacted-windows-7-ultimate?forum=winserverDS). I know it's from windows 7, but i think the main problem you have is with the DNS configuration and it's very well explained there.

I'll summarise the link above here:

> @Meinolf Weber's answer
>
> If domain machines contain **public DNS** servers as 200.88.127.23 and 196.3.81.5 you will always have trouble.
>
> Remove them on ALL domain machines and run `ipconfig /flushdns` and `ipconfig /registerdns` and **reboot** clients and domain member servers and restart the netlogon service on DCs instead reboot.
>
> For internet access please configure the FORWARDERS in the DNS server properties in the DNS management console with the public DNS servers.

Explanation:

> You can't join a machine to the domain using public IP because **it is trying to locate your domain to the public IP** which has not information of the private build domain.
>   Use **only local IP** in the clients NIC.

Hope it helps, if not please give more detailed information of the issue as well as the DNS configuration (screenshot or whatever you can).

**EDIT 1:** also check "time settings" on both machines, i know it might seem silly, but that sometimes gives DNS and DC issues. **Check** IPv6, could be another probable cause of the issues you're having (Go to the network and sharing center, modify the properties of the NIC and unselect TCP/IPv6).

I'd check first IPv6, that'll save you work if it's only that.

**EDIT 2:** again, i would recommend changing the IPs (if possible) to another network, as long as the 169.254.x.x is used (assigned) when there's no DHCP server, but as you say they can ping to each other, it may not be necessary the problem.

I can see there's no router in the network but, a Windows Server **should** be providing DHCP, otherwise things like DNS suffix don't work.
So **check** that:
 - You have the DNS role installed and configured to support AD.

## SOLVED on answer below

The explanation i would give for this is that "secure communication" is an often requirement, thing that *internal network* doesn't provide.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I disabled ipv6 on both, timesettings are equal and it's not public ip, it is internal network between machines.

Comment: @johntrue Are the IPs static?

Comment: @johntrue Can you ping in **both** directions?